# laptop with windows - replacing original HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop

Because of controlled obsolescence, there are only 4 laptop models with a HDD of 2tb available across all Canada.

There exist 3 and 4 tb HDDs.

What's the simplest method to change the original laptop HDD with a new one, without having to repay for the included Windows system on the laptop ?

If I clone the disk, will Windows still works ?

Does new laptop comes with a Windows CD ?
Can I just replace the disk and install Windows on the disk ?  Will it be allowed, since the Windows was already installed on the original laptop disk ?

Comment: Any of the hard drive cloning tools will do this. Going from a small disk to a larger disk is easiest.  No a hard disk clone will not invalidate the Windows activation, so long as the rest of the system remains the same.

Comment: @mokubai is correct - provided your disk isnot larger then 2tb - Your system may not be able to handle larger disks, or may require a different boot method (uefi) to accommodate it.

Comment: @davidgo Well yes, if the old system is BIOS based then it won't support GPT disks (or any disks larger than 2TB), and going from BIOS to UEFI (converting from MBR to GPT) is likely to be an utter pain... but all *current* systems should be UEFI/GPT, and OP appears to be asking about *new* machines so I made the assumption that this wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some caveats here,and I'll put them at the end, but the major point is that this is *totally do-able* and should be a simple case of cloning the older disk onto the new disk.

> What's the simplest method to change the original laptop HDD with a new one, without having to repay for the included Windows system on the laptop ?

Using any of a number of disk cloning softwares. [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/) or whatever tool claims to work.  Probably Aomei Partition Manager will too.

The absolute best thing you can do is to clone the disk in its entirety, reserved partitions, recovery partitions and all. You might want to resize your data partition, but that's the worst of it.

This should "just" work, I've use Macrium and everything went fine.

Worst case, you have to boot into a Windows Recovery USB and run

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

> If I clone the disk, will Windows still works ?

Yes.

> Does new laptop comes with a Windows CD ?

Generally no.  Most modern machines come with a partition that is your factory restore partition and no CDs.  Windows can [copy this off to a USB stick for you](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive) (Windows 8 link, Windows 10 likely the same).

Most OEM manufacturers (Dell, HP, etc) also often provide yet another tool that replicates this functionality.

> Can I just replace the disk and install Windows on the disk ?

If you've created the recovery USB as above, almost certainly yes.  You will want to back up your data files somewhere though.

> Will it be allowed, since the Windows was already installed on the original laptop disk ?

Yes.  Windows 8 stored the product key for OEM machines in an area of the firmware and activation read this key and registered the machine for you.  Windows 10 stores your machine ID with Microsoft so that you can activate over the internet easily.

I've done the Windows 8 to 10 upgrade, then reformatted and reinstalled 10 cleanly and at no point did I enter a product key for the new install.  I know this works.

---

There is at least one major caveat though.

If you have an old system that has a BIOS based firmware (or uses the UEFI "Compatibility Support Module" (CSM) to emulate BIOS) then you are probably using an MBR partitioned disk.  MBR ***does not*** [support disks greater than 1.7TB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2581408).  For >2TB disks you need to use the GPT partition scheme, and if you want to be able to boot from a GPT disk then you ***must*** have a UEFI based firmware.  If you don't know what any of that means and you bought the machine recently, then you *should* have a UEFI/GPT system and are "good to go" and can just get a larger disk.

From bitter experience I know if you want to use a >2TB disk on a BIOS based system then you need another <2TB disk partitioned as MBR from which to boot.

This shouldn't be a problem for any machine bought in the last 4-5 years though.  All current machines should, from factory, have a UEFI firmware properly set up with a GPT disk.  Any that don't have this deserve the manufacturer to be publicly ridiculed.